# javascript says undefined for json laravel model

Tags: json, laravel-4

This is my controller:

```
$sibling_details = student::whereRaw('family_id like ?', array($data['familyid']));
return Response::json(
        array(
            'success'=>true, 
            'msg'=>'Family Found', 
            'family_details'=>$family_details->first(),
            'sibling_details'=>$sibling_details
            )
        );
```

In my javascript of my view following is working fine:

```
  $("#family_details").html(data.family_details.father_name);
```

BUT following is saying undefined:

```
  $("#sibling_details").html(data.sibling_details[0].name);
```

Following Line shows:

```
[object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]
```

as $sibling_details contains FOUR Rows

How can I retrieve data from sibling_details object??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try actual fetching your query with `->get()`.

```
$sibling_details = Student::whereRaw('family_id like ?', array($data['familyid']))->get();
```